# include and include_once issue in PHP

Tags: php, include

I currently working on a PHP project. I copy the project file to my local box. It runs fine except one thing.

Here is the folder hierarchy:

```
root/index.php
root/event/admin/list.php 
root/event/admin/functions.php
```

In the index.php, there is a line:

```
<?php include ("event/admin/list.php"); ?>
```

which should include the list.php

However in the list.php, there is a line:

```
<?php include_once "event/admin/functions.php";?>
```

Since the list.php is not in the root directory, `event/admin/functions.php` did not get call and my local `index.php` fail to load this part.
But the production is working fine.

Does anyone know what happened? Is that a way to setup include/include_once always use ROOT directory without using something like $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good idea to use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], in my opinion. You can do so like this:

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/path/to/file.php");
```

However, try replacing he code in list.php with this:

```
<?php include_once "../../event/admin/functions.php";?>
```

This is a known issue relating to relative paths. Thus, DOCUMENT_ROOT is preferable. Alternatively, you can edit include_path.

Comment: I found include_path in production is `include_path = ".:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php"` , do you know what does that means?

Answer (score 1):

Set the [include path](http://php.net/include_path) to whatever is useful for your probject.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue related to relative paths.  You can either include your files from an absolute path, or modify your [include_path in php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) to use your doc root, and specify files relative to there.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the [include path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) configuration between the two machines.